# Rails - correct db query returns empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Can anyone please explain me, why my db queries return empty, when I have data in my table?

```
Event.all
```

returns

```
...
Event Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: 1, created_at: "2013-08-01 12:27:36", updated_at: "2013-08-01 12:27:36"> 
...
```

etc,

While

```
Event.where(created_at: Date.today)
```

gives me

```
Event Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."created_at" = '2013-08-01'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Where is everything?

Comment: What DBM are you using? Typically we'd truncate the DateTime value to a date in the query to make it match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `created_at` **is a DateTime**, but you are **comparing it to a Date** (no time).
You need to **Cast the field as a Date** to get all Events created today:

```
Event.where('CAST(events.created_at as DATE) = ?', Date.today)
```

**Attention:** *The syntax may change depending on your Data-base system (PostGreSQL / MySQL, etc).*

Hope this helps!

Useful link:

- http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/cast-date

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your actual query -

`SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."created_at" = '2013-08-01'`

You are looking for a record with `created_at` **equals** `2013-08-01`, but in actuality, the record you are trying to search for - the `created_at` field equals `2013-08-01 12:27:36`.

Change your statement to do a search for `created_at` that **contains** `2013-08-01`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the created_at: attribute (assuming that it was created in the migration timestamps) also stores the time. So it will never equal a simple date. You're best option is to parse the date and then compare it.